# Why does perl report an incorrect line number for this warning regarding an uninitialized value used in an elsif?

Tags: perl, warnings, initialization

I'm getting a strange warning against some Perl code and I'm hoping the SO-brain can help.

The code in question is:

```
sub add_observation {
    my $self = shift;
    my $observation = shift;

    my $result = $observation->get_datum_result($self->{datum_name});
    if(!(defined $result)) {
        croak("Datum '$self->{datum_name}' not defined for this observation: ". Dumper($observation));
    }
    $self->{result} |= $result;
    my $observation_time = $observation->get_time();

    if($self->{result} == 0){
        $self->set_start_time($observation_time);
    }
    if($result != 0) {
        $self->set_end_time($observation_time);
        $self->{end_threshold} = $observation_time->epoch() + $self->{timeout};
    }
    elsif($observation_time->epoch() > $self->{end_threshold}) {
        $self->{complete} = 1;
    }

    return $self->{result}; 
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric gt (>) at Performance/BadSpan.pm line 67 (#1)
```

Line 67 equates to the `if($result != 0) {` line.

My problem is twofold:

1. Why is Perl stating that `$result` is undefined, when there's some guard code preceding it that ensures that it *is* defined
2. Why is Perl complaining about a numeric gt, when there is no numeric gt. The rubric associated with this warning does indicate that Perl might optimise your code and the warning refers to the optimized operators, but does that mean that a `!=` is 'optimized' to a `>` and a `<`?

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for the update to the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is the version of `perl`?

Given

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $x;

if ( $x ) {
    print "here\n";
}
elsif ( $x > 1 ) {
    print "there\n";
}
```

`perl` 5.10.1 correctly outputs:

`Use of uninitialized value $x in numeric gt (>) at C:\Temp\t.pl line 8.`

Given that `elsif` does not stand alone, but is part of the `if` statement, there might have been a bug in earlier versions which reported the line number of the enclosing `if` statement.

[This post](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.changes/2008/04/msg21562.html) and [this entry in `perltodo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltodo.html#eliminate-incorrect-line-numbers-in-warnings) seem relevant:

> #### eliminate incorrect line numbers in warnings
>
> This code
>
> ```
>   1. use warnings;
>   2. my $undef;
>   3.
>   4. if ($undef == 3) {
>   5. } elsif ($undef == 0) {
>   6. }
> ```
>
> used to produce this output:
>
> ```
>   Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at wrong.pl line 4.
>   Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at wrong.pl line 4.
> ```
>
> where the line of the second warning was misreported - it should be line 5. Rafael fixed this - the problem arose because there was no nextstate OP between the execution of the if and the `elsif`, hence `PL_curcop` still reports that the currently executing line is line 4. The solution was to inject a nextstate OPs for each `elsif`, although it turned out that the nextstate OP needed to be a nulled OP, rather than a live nextstate OP, else other line numbers became misreported. (Jenga!)
>
> The problem is more general than `elsif` (although the `elsif` case is the most common and the most confusing). Ideally this code
>
> ```
>    1. use warnings;
>    2. my $undef;
>    3.
>    4. my $a = $undef + 1;
>    5. my $b
>    6. = $undef
>    7. + 1;
> ```
>
> would produce this output
>
> ```
>    Use of uninitialized value $undef in addition (+) at wrong.pl line 4.
>    Use of uninitialized value $undef in addition (+) at wrong.pl line 7.
> ```
>
> (rather than lines 4 and 5), but this would seem to require every OP to carry (at least) line number information.
>
> What might work is to have an optional line number in memory just before the BASEOP structure, with a flag bit in the op to say whether it's present. Initially during compile every OP would carry its line number. Then add a late pass to the optimiser (potentially combined with repack the optree) which looks at the two ops on every edge of the graph of the execution path. If the line number changes, flags the destination OP with this information. Once all paths are traced, replace every op with the flag with a nextstate-light op (that just updates `PL_curcop`), which in turn then passes control on to the true op. All ops would then be replaced by variants that do not store the line number. (Which, logically, why it would work best in conjunction with repack the optree, as that is already copying/reallocating all the OPs)
>
> (Although I should note that we're not certain that doing this for the general case is worth it)

Here is the actual [commit](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/f6f3a1fea2bda9d33f9cc5367b630a21738c9def). Given that the commit happened in April 2008, I am assuming the fix was included in the 5.8.9 release (see [perlhist](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html)).

Comment: It says "Rafael fixed this", but it doesn't say when/what version this occurred in. :(

Comment: @Ether added the link to the commit: http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/f6f3a1fea2bda9d33f9cc5367b630a21738c9def

Comment: Nice bit of archaeology there.

Comment: I'm on version 5.8.8
Thanks for some great research. I'm working to move our servers to at least 5.10, if not 5.12... here's another reason why :)

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a numeric gt (`>`) on the line

```
elsif($observation_time->epoch() > $self->{end_threshold}) {
```

which is the `elsif` associated with the `if` on line 67.  Maybe the warning message has the line number wrong.  Could either `$observation_time->epoch()` or `$self->{end_threshold}` be undefined?

Comment: I've some investigation to do there, but you my be right... begs the question, why is Perl reporting it on line 67... but maybe that has something to do with the mentioned optimisation.

Comment: Yes... that's the problem... as it turns out, the logic of the whole function is off, so I'll be re-writing it.
I'll accept this answer, unless anyone (or you) comes up with the reason why it is reporting on line 67 instead of line 74

Comment: Why the line number is off is probably a question for someone who knows the guts of the Perl interpreter.  I just know enough about how these things are normally put together to consider that a plausible way it could misbehave.  You might be advised to file a bug at http://rt.perl.org/perlbug/

Comment: The bug was fixed in April 2008: http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/f6f3a1fea2bda9d33f9cc5367b630a21738c9def See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `>` in the `elsif` clause.  Check those values.